# Fancybox Popup not removing overlay in Chrome and IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, fancybox-2

http://www.teachhub.com/sevcik-tester-ooyala

Fancybox close event is not removing the dark overlay in Chrome and IE.  Firefox works great.  I'm using fancybox 2. The commented out items below, I've tried forcing the close event and it's not working.  The main window closes, but the dark overlay remains.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.noConflict();
});
</script>
<div style="width: 312px;">

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery("a.videolink").fancybox({

  closeClick  : true,
  helpers   : { 
  overlay : {closeClick: true}
 },


      'afterClose': function () {
      videoPlayer.pause();
      //jQuery("#fancybox-wrap").hide();
      //jQuery("#fancybox-wrap").empty();
//jQuery("#fancybox-overlay").hide();
//jQuery("#fancybox-overlay").empty();
     //jQuery('#fancybox-overlay').unbind();
      }
   });
});
</script>
<script src='http://player.ooyala.com/v3/apikey'></script>

<p style="font-weight: bold; color: red; font-size: 18px; line-height: 21px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">Welcome to TeachHUB.com</p>

<!-- The Video Thumbnail -->
<a class="videolink" href="#videocontainer" title="">
<img src="/sites/default/files/homepage-video-player.jpg" style="float: left; padding: 0px 15px 15px 10px;"/>
</a>

<!-- The Video Object -->
<div id="videocontainer">
        <div id='playerwrapper' style='width:480px;height:360px;'></div>

<script>
var videoPlayer = OO.Player.create('playerwrapper','R0ZjB2NTqDw3YRWba9RIpRnF6D9lRYKP',   {
   // additional params go here
});

videoPlayer.play();
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you close fancybox in Chrome, it triggers 1500+ js errors .... it's most likely a loop.

try loading a single instance of jQuery (ideally the latest version) ... so far, I have found 3 different versions (v1.7.2, v1.4.4 and v1.3.1).