# close button on fancyBox not working with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, fancybox-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close Button on FancyBox Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071616/close-button-on-fancybox-not-working)

The close button on fancyBox 2.0 not working with Google Chrome. 
However it works with Explorer and Firefox.

**EDIT**: (moved from comments) Here is the link http://botarela.fr/Poaceae/Description%20detail/Epillet.html

Comment: I guess you need to post your code or a link to see the issue ourselves so we can use debugging tools ;)

Comment: It appears to work in the site examples http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples any chance you can show your code?

Comment: Here is the link : http://botarela.fr/Poaceae/Description%20detail/Epillet.html

Comment: @user1774560 Literally just tested it and it works fine... (Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m)

Comment: You asked exactly the same question an hour before this.

Comment: I have the same Chrome version (Chrome 21.0.1180.89 m) reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading two instances of jQuery when you only need one (ideally the latest version).

You can see a similar issue [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13021907/1055987) because that.